# I want my textarea to have a fixed width

Tags: html, input, textarea

I have seen it on some sites where the textarea input can by drawn only downward but not to sideways.

```html
<textarea cols="10" rows="5" charswidth="23" name="text_body"></textarea>
```

I have tried those but the width is still extendable. Please how can I do this?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```css
textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}
```

```html
<textarea cols="10" rows="5" charswidth="23" name="text_body"></textarea>
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ou1htm72/)

[MDN docs for `resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize)

Comment: Awesome possum!

Answer (score 5):

This can be achieved via CSS.

```html
    <textarea cols="10" rows="5" charswidth="23" name="text_body" style="resize:vertical"></textarea>
```